# Sharepoint OOTB webservice to get all subsite url and their titles

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, moss

I'm using MOSS OOTB WebServices wherein I in need a webservice method name which gives me all subsite Urls and their titles..

I'm using GetWebCollection method of Webs.asmx webserive but this method is not giving me parent's title.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get current web, use [GetWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webs.webs.getweb%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method.

Alternatively you can try [GetAllSubWebCollection](http://www.google.lv/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webs.webs.getallsubwebcollection%28v=office.12%29.aspx&ei=gc6WTsmaLozFtAbB7dCPBA&usg=AFQjCNEWZLpcE6F0TtwZp73G_2wkCTlk4A&sig2=jckpnNyM8njW_BByBGoxAQ), because it Returns the titles and URLs of all sites within the current site collection rather than [GetWebCollection](http://www.google.lv/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webs.webs.getwebcollection%28v=office.12%29.aspx&ei=C8-WTp2pOZH5sgaAw4TxAw&usg=AFQjCNFztjAd5DZ7DdyZ5DfeUu16t9IZug&sig2=KT3R-3zDOu2A3ctPFA3Ghg), which returns only the titles and URLs of all sites directly **beneath** the current site.

Comment: Appreciable!! Thanks for giving me quick and best solution, is there any method wherein I get only parent site and immediate sub-site's URLs with titles not the sub-sites of the sub-sites.

Comment: @Kuldeep Shige just use GetWeb (to get only parent) and GetWebCollection (to get immediate sub-sites)